# Wordpress Divi updates don't save

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a bit of an amateur so I'm sure I've missed something.

I'm running Divi on Wordpress. When i go to update a page, I get the "Your updates couldn't be saved" error. My Wordpress site, as well as it's CPanel, also are loading unusually slowly, which I think is related to the issue. After working on this for a bit, both my site and it's CPanel will fail to load, giving me a "can't establish a secure connection to the server" error. The third symptom, which I can't make heads nor tails of, when I click "update" in the page editor, my browser will often (but not always) launch another tab/pop-up either displaying a preview of the edits or the "pages" page on the WP admin side. All of these issues are new (although I've had similar loading speed issues in the past with this site).

Thinking it may be an overload on my server (which happened due to an attack a few months ago), I let it sit for a few days with no luck. Then, thinking it may be a caching issue on my end, I changed my DNS servers, cleared my browser cache, tried private browsing, used my phone, used different wifi and cellular networks. All to no avail. I briefly had slight luck using my phone as a hotspot, but it only temporarily improved the loading speeds.

I also tried disabling plugins. I made sure everything was up to date. No help.

I went into my wp-config.php file and increased the memory limit to 128M and the WP-max memory limit to 256M. This helped briefly–I could update and save one page but when I tried to change the next, I was back to base 1. I've also increased the memory limits in my .htaccess file. I don't have access to my PHP.init file (there are often delays reaching my host so I'm trying to avoid relying on them when possible).

My last guess (which I have yet to implement) is to update my PHP. That said, I'm running 7.3.6 and had no issue updating the site a few days ago so I'm not sure that's the problem, unless divi's newest update has compatibility issues with 7.3 versions of PHP...

Any further ideas would be greatly appreciated! I'm partway through a cosmetic update (which, I know should be done on a staging site but sometimes best practices are best learnt through mistakes like this) so my site looks somewhat half-finished. That is, I'm anxious to be able to edit it again.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you try to save something, Divi will make a request through admin-ajax.php, it often happens that a security firewall detects that as a threat (which is obviously not), thus giving you the failed save message. Can you ask you host to check the rules that are triggered and whitelist that action? It can also come from plugins like Wordfence, make sure to whitelist it there too.

You can also attach that layout as JSON here, I can test it on my own server and if I can save changes, we should be on the right path.